# Throwing exceptions: Node.js vs Gevent

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, exception, gevent

Someone at a meetup yesterday told me that if a callback throws an exception in Node.js, it will crash the entire process. But if a greenlet throws an uncaught exception in Gevent, it only crashes the greenlet.

I don't have experience with Gevent, and am wondering if that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Node.js apps crash upon uncaught exception? Yes. See, e.g., http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/

Do uncaught exceptions in Gevent greenlets only bring down the greenlet in question? Yes. See, e.g., http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html and in particular `Greenlet.exception` which
"holds the exception instance raised by the function if the greenlet has finished with an error," thus making the exception instance available to the rest of the process, which did not crash.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an exmaple code that shows that when a greenlet throws an uncaught excpetion, the whole process won't be crashed. The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/flyer103/7904968) and the output is as following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run  
  result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)  
File "test_exception_greenlet.py", line 31, in _fail  
  raise Exception('you fail')  
Exception: you fail  
<Greenlet at 0x8b5cc5c: <bound method TestgException._fail of <__main__.TestgException object at 0x8bd4a0c>>> failed with Exception  

win ready? True    
fail ready? True  
win successful()? True  
fail successful()? False  
exception: Exception('you fail',)
```

When using `gevent` to implemenet concurrency tasks, you should generate some `coroutines`, namely `greenlets`, and then the main thread should switch to a special `greenlet` named **hub** and then the loop happens among `greenlets`. The workflow is like this:

> main thread -> one greenlet -> hub greenlet -> a greenlet -> hub greenlet -> a greenlet -> ... -> some greenlet -> main thread -> ... (maybe enters the loop again)

From here, you should know how a greenlet runs internally. A greenlet is an instance of `Greenlet`. When a greenlet runs, it invokes its `run()` method. Here is the source code of `run()` in `Greenlet` class:

```
def run(self):
    try:
        if self._start_event is None:
            self._start_event = _dummy_event
        else:
            self._start_event.stop()
        try:
            result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            self._report_error(sys.exc_info())
            return
        self._report_result(result)
    finally:
        self.__dict__.pop('_run', None)
        self.__dict__.pop('args', None)
        self.__dict__.pop('kwargs', None)
```

The `_run()` method here is a binding with a task you want to run as a greenlet. From here you could see that if an exception happens, it will be caught and reported by `_report_error()` method. By reading the source code of `_report_error()` and `_report_result()` which is invoked by the former, you know that it catches the exception and just the greenlet dies but not the whole process. When a greenlet raises an uncaught exception, it dies and the `hub` greenlet won't schedule it any more.

If you're insterested in the implementation of `Greenlet`, here is the [source code](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/blob/master/gevent/greenlet.py)

Comment: you forgot to add the answer ;)

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli, sorry that I don't know what you mean. My answer is the first sentence and the other is explanation.